# Ng-show with sidenav bar

Tags: html, css, angularjs, responsive-design

So I have been trying to work on a website and I seem to have stumbled upon an error. I'm working on a single page website with angular routing.

I'm not using bootstrap, and I would prefer to stay without it. My problem is I'm trying to open up (or show) a side bar when The menu is clicked.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="w3-top" ng-controller="mainController">
<ul class="w3-navbar w3-white w3-card-2" id="myNavbar">
  <li>
    <a href="" ng-click="redirectToOtherPage()" class="w3-wide"><img src="./img/monkey.png" width="75" height="75"></a>
  </li>
  <!-- Right-sided navbar links -->
  <li class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
    <a href="" ng-click="redirectToPackages()"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> PACKAGES</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="redirectToOpenPlay()"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> OPEN PLAY</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="redirectToGallery()"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> GALLERY</a>
    <a href="" ng-click="redirectToContact()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a>
    <!--<a href="" ng-click="redirectToSignup()"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> SIGN UP</a>-->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/goinbananas/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fb"></i></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/goinbananas_frenchies/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-insta"></i></a>
  </li>
  <!-- Hide right-floated links on small screens and replace them with a menu icon -->
  <li>
    <div class="w3-right w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">
      <a href="" ng-click="sidenav = !sidenav" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-bars w3-padding-right w3-padding-left"></i></a>
    </div>
        <!-- Sidenav on small screens when clicking the menu icon -->
      <div class="w3-sidenav w3-white w3-card-2 w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:block" ng-show="sidenav" ng-controller="mainController">
        <a href="" ng-click="redirectToPackages()"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> PACKAGES</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="redirectToOpenPlay()"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> OPEN PLAY</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="redirectToGallery()"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> GALLERY</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="redirectToContact()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a>
        <!--<a href="" ng-click="redirectToSignup()"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> SIGN UP</a>-->
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/goinbananas/"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fb"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/goinbananas_frenchies/"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-insta"></i></a>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $location){
$scope.redirectToOtherPage = function(){
  $location.path("/");
};
$scope.redirectToContact = function(){
  $location.path("/contactus");
};
$scope.redirectToPackages = function(){
  $location.path("/packages");
};
$scope.redirectToSignup = function(){
  $location.path("/signup");
};
$scope.redirectToGallery = function(){
  $location.path("/gallery");
};
$scope.redirectToOpenPlay = function(){
  $location.path("/openplay");
};
$scope.sidenav = false;
});
```

Am I missing something here? I've been stumped all day and I would like to at least feel like I'm going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Your module should have depndency injected,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
```

Comment: Ok, but what does that do for me? All that did for me was not load any page.

Comment: you need to have dependencies injected for angular module! check if there is any error on console

Answer (score 0):

Try using a function on ng-click event.

Instead of

```
 ng-click="sidenav = !sidenav"
```

try using

```
 ng-click="openMenu()"
```

and in controller

```
 $scope.openMenu = function(){
  $scope.sidenav = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not injecting dependencies

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location',
function($scope, $location){
    $scope.redirectToOtherPage = function(){
      $location.path("/");
    };
    $scope.redirectToContact = function(){
      $location.path("/contactus");
    };
    $scope.redirectToPackages = function(){
      $location.path("/packages");
    };
    $scope.redirectToSignup = function(){
      $location.path("/signup");
    };
    $scope.redirectToGallery = function(){
      $location.path("/gallery");
    };
    $scope.redirectToOpenPlay = function(){
      $location.path("/openplay");
    };
    $scope.sidenav = false;
});
```